# A Lover Spurned - A broken heart cries, waiting for your love. Figure out their name so that you can engage in a little rebound romance

Tags: riddle

Is this about all the heroin? After everything? And this is how you repay me? I don't just mean keeping you clothed and respectable looking. I don't just mean saving your life. I thought we were close. I've been firmly with you everywhere you go. Even my words, you ass! Everything coming out of my mouth, coming from my tongue reflects you and what you bring me to experience.

Now you say you don't need me? Well, I don't need you. Go off, have your adventures, but remember this conversation when you come crawling back. And don't until you lose some weight. I'm not ending up at my limit again for some hot mess like you.

**Figure out this lonely heart's name so you can make them feel a little better and perhaps engage in a rebound romance.**

To clarify, the lonely heart you're trying to identify is the speaker.

Comment: For those starting to guess, look at my other riddles. Just about every bit is a clue. Connecting one bit to an answer isn't going to get it.

Comment: This reads like a letter from Kurt Cobain to Courtney Love so strongly that I was tempted to post that as a joke answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> A belt

Is this about all the heroin?

> Heroin refers to belting an arm before shooting up.

I don't just mean keeping you clothed and respectable looking.

> Clothed and respectable as belts suspend pants and are classy as can be.

I don't just mean saving your life.

> A (security) belt can save your life.

Everything ... from my tongue reflects you

> The *toungue* of a belt is usually metallic and reflective.

Now you say you don't need me? ... remember this conversation when you come crawling back. And don't until you lose some weight.

> The belt is no longer needed because the wearer has gained weight and their pants now stay on. Notice that the "and don't until" bit is written in such a way that it could mean that he/she won't decide to come back till there is weight loss and the belt is needed again.

I'm not ending up at my limit again

> The limit is the last punch hole of the belt.

Thanks to the OP for his feedback on this answer. My old answer is included under the line.

---

My guess is:

> A security belt

It's all about the heroin

> In this context, the heroin is a person belted up

I don't just mean keeping you clothed and respectable looking.

> A security belt is not just something you put on like clothes.

I don't just mean saving your life.

> A security belt can save your life but it can do more.

I've been firmly with you everywhere you go.

> A security belt is tight firmly to the passenger.

Everything ... from my tongue reflects you

> The *toungue* of a security belt is usually metallic and reflective.

Now you say you don't need me? ... Go off

> When you put off a security belt, you don't need it any more.

And don't until you lose some weight. I'm not ending up at my limit again for some hot mess like you.

> Makes sense. If you're fat, you're going to pull the security belt to its limit.

### Update (to the old answer)

After thinking about it once again, the solution could be also just:

> A belt

This would explain the "ass" part better, although other clues would then sound more fanciful.

Comment: I think you got it!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is a

> shoe

If only because they have a mouth, most notably a tongue, and the

> wearer brings it to its "experiences" by walking, and can possibly outgrow it

Also, they keep people clothed and respectable looking enough, some places forbid service without having one or the other? The heroin bit throws me off, however.

Answer (score -3):

Heroin: **H**, after everything: at the end of the word.
You ass: **U S**.
To experience -> to be: **B**.

It's

> Bush

who let the national debt reach unprecedented levels (= at my limit again)?

Comment: Why does 'experience' give B?

Comment: I guess **to be** $\to$ **to** ***exist***, not **to experience**.